# Service bus gateway high memory on SharePoint Server

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I have service bus high memory on my sharepoint server?
i have 10gb mem. Is this normal?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

depends because so many services use it so anything could be taking up resources. is it constant or peaks?

Check the performance monitor on the server:

> To access the Service Bus performance counters, open the Performance
>   Monitor. In the Perfomance pane, expand Monitoring Tools, and then
>   click Performance Monitor. In the main pane click the green plus (+)
>   icon. In the Add Counters window, scroll to the Service Bus
>   performance counter groups.
>
> To open the Performance Monitor on Windows Server, click Start, then
>   Administrative Tools, then Performance Monitor. To open the
>   Performance Monitor application on Windows Server 2012, type
>   Performance Monitor in the Start screen, then click the Performance
>   Monitor icon.

I would advise you look at the following url to check against set values.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj192996.aspx

also here for the architecture:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193012.aspx

as you can see its dependent on how your system was setup would determine resource allocation.

if your asking for my input ;) , 2.2gb for Service bus gateway is quite high if its constant. If its during high usage like workflows,  access (permissions), SQL traffic then its ok for a short period due to bottleneck.